# ¿Cómo implemento un subgrupo en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con mi consulta de MySQL en la que quiero traer solo los datos más recientes de `pedidos_reportes` Ejemplo:

> Juan reporto un pedido en el `ID` 45 a las 14:00 HRS
> Después de ello,
> Pedro volvio a crear un reporte en el mismo `ID` pero a las 15:00 HRS

Y lo que yo debo mostrar es solo el registro de Pedro.

```
SELECT pedidos.*,
reporte.*,
usuarios.*,
pedidos_reportes.*
FROM pedidos  
LEFT JOIN (
    select id_pedido,
    MAX(fecha_modificacion)
    FROM pedidos_reportes
    GROUP BY id_pedido
) pedidos_reportes
ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN reporte  
ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
LEFT JOIN usuarios 
ON pedidosreportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
 WHERE fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()
```

Creé un subgrupo con un `LEFT JOIN` pero al parecer tengo un problema el cual no me permite hacer la consulta correctamente, y me muestra el siguiente error:

```
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1054 - La columna 'fecha_modificacion' en where clause es desconocida
```

Estas son mis tablas:
[image: Tablas con relaciones]

En esta consulta modificada me da el error:

```
#1054 - La columna 'pedidos_reportes.id_reporte' en on clause es desconocida

SELECT pedidos.*,
reporte.*,
usuarios.*,
pedidos_reportes.*
FROM pedidos  
LEFT JOIN (
    select id_pedido,
    MAX(fecha_modificacion) as fecha_modificacion
    FROM pedidos_reportes
    WHERE fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()
    GROUP BY id_pedido
) pedidos_reportes
ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN reporte  
ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
LEFT JOIN usuarios 
ON pedidos_reportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
```

Comment: La columna `fecha_modificacion` pertenece a la tabla `pedidos_reportes`. Tú usas la columna por fuera, en el `WHERE`, pero la tabla `pedidos_reportes` no participa en la consulta *por fuera*, sino en una sub-consulta, por tanto, si quieres filtrar por esa columna tendrías que poner el WHERE en la sub-consulta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me regresa el siguiente mensaje:  La columna 'pedidos_reportes.id_reporte' en on clause es desconocida

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la nueva consulta al final de la pregunta? Puede que hayas cometido algún error adaptando el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano Listo ya la agregue

Comment: ¿Esta consulta no te da los datos que esperas obtener? `SELECT 
  pedidos_reportes.id_pedido,
  MAX(pedidos_reportes.fecha_modificacion) AS max_fecha
FROM pedidos  
LEFT JOIN pedidos_reportes ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN reporte  ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON pedidosreportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
WHERE pedidos_reportes.fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()` Yo no termino de ver claro cuál es el sentido de una sub-consulta aquí.

Comment: @A.Cedano Solo se trata sobre un desarrollo en el que las personas seleccionan el ID del producto para reprogramar una fecha de entrega, pero este producto lo pueden volver a reprogramar, entonces cuando ellos miran los productos que estan reprogramados no debo mostrar IDs duplicados, solo debo mostrar el registro que sea más reciente, por eso es el subgrupo. porque tengo más cosas filtros en la consulta.

Comment: Y me sigue dando el error: La columna 'pedidosreportes.id_usuario' en on clause es desconocida

Comment: Ya, es que en ese JOIN hay un *typo*, falta el guión bajo, debes ponerlo así: `LEFT JOIN usuarios ON pedidos_reportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id WHERE`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126243/discussion-between-david-valdivia-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que hacer `JOIN` entre la tabla original (la que contiene todos los valores) y la vista (subgrupo, que contiene sólo identificador y fecha):

```
SELECT pedidos.*
     , reporte.*
     , usuarios.*
     , pedidos_reportes.*
  FROM pedidos  
    LEFT JOIN pedidos_reportes
      ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT id_pedido
                      , MAX(fecha_modificacion) as fecha_modificacion
                   FROM pedidos_reportes
                   WHERE fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()
                   GROUP BY id_pedido
               ) pedidos_reportes_max
      ON     pedidos_reportes.id_pedido = pedidos_reportes_max.id_pedido
        AND  pedidos_reportes.fecha_modificacion = pedidos_reportes_max.fecha_modificacion
    LEFT JOIN reporte  
      ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
    LEFT JOIN usuarios 
      ON pedidos_reportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Para poder utilizar la columna en el `Where` tienes que darle un alias, y así el motor sabe de donde viene esa columna, ya que lo que devuelve la función Max no es lo mismo que lo que le "entró".

```
SELECT pedidos.*,
reporte.*,
usuarios.*,
pedidos_reportes.*
FROM pedidos  
LEFT JOIN (
    select id_pedido,
    MAX(fecha_modificacion) as fecha_modificacion
    FROM pedidos_reportes
    GROUP BY id_pedido
) pedidos_reportes
ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN reporte  
ON pedidos.id_pedido = reporte.id 
LEFT JOIN usuarios 
ON pedidos.id_usuario = usuarios.id
 WHERE fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()
```

Comment: al parecer me sigue dando un error. #1054 - La columna 'pedidos_reportes.id_reporte' en on clause es desconocida