# Seleccionar registro ultima fecha

Tags: sql, filtro

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos:

- fecha
- codcuenta
- valorcancelado

quiero traer datos de la ultima fecha de pago, pero me esta trayendo las fechas anteriores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El query que estoy usando es el siguiente

```
SELECT max(fechacancelado) Fecha,codcuenta,valorcancelado
FROM costosliquidacion 
WHERE valorcancelado > 0 
GROUP BY codcuenta, valorcancelado 
ORDER BY fecha desc
```

Alguien que me oriente, gracias.

Comment: `select top ` no te sirve?

Comment: No me sirve, por que el codcuenta varia, en este caso hay dos pero puede ser mas de dos.

Comment: bueno, al where le falta la fecha...

Comment: Ultima fecha de pago ¿de todas o de cada una de las cuentas?

Comment: de cada una de las cuentas y ultima fecha,, es decir traer la ultima fecha con el código y valorcancelado.

Comment: Podes mostrar cual es tu salida esperada? porque con todo lo que decis, no queda nada claro

Comment: Lo que necesito que muestre es lo seleccionado en la imagen de la pregunta que hice, solamente esos dos registros,, en este caso pero puede pasar que hayan mas en otro mes.

Comment: Me suena a [éste caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460096).

Answer (score 0):

La manera de hacerlo es usando el condicional.
Y tal y como haces, debes obtener la última fecha de la misma tabla.

```
SELECT *
FROM costosliquidacion
WHERE fechacancelado = (SELECT MAX(fechacancelado) 
                        FROM costosliquidacion)
AND valorcancelado > 0
```

Comment: trae la ultima fecha,, pero necesito que muestre los codcuenta y valorcancelado que están dentro de ese mes.

Comment: Por eso esta pidiendo todos los datos de la tabla. Además la pregunta dice específicamente que quieres la ultima fecha por que la tuya trae los anteriores. Si tu requerimiento ha cambiado, y ahora buscas el mes, debes especificarlo antes.

Comment: Prueba a hacer algo así:
SELECT * FROM costosliquidacion where valorcancelado > 0 order by Fecha desc limit 1;

Answer (score 0):

Debes obtener siempre fecha máxima para cada `codcuenta`, como se desconoce (porque puede cambiar con cada transacción), lo mejor es ordenarlos y obtener el Last value o el First value. Esta aproximación es usando una Window Function para asignar el id #1 siempre al último registro. (Es decir la fecha máxima de cada codcuenta)

```
  with x as (
SELECT codcuenta,
       valorcancelado,
       fechacancelado,
        row_number() over (partition by codcuenta order by fechacancelado desc) as last

FROM costosliquidacion
WHERE valorcancelado > 0
GROUP BY codcuenta, valorcancelado
)
select * from x where last = 1
```

Dentro de la vista CTE llamada x se encapsula la lógica que ordenará los elementos por  codcuenta. Después se filtra para obtener siempre el más reciente de acuerdo con el codcuenta. Como el orden es descendente, siempre tendrás en primer lugar el último, así se podrá filtrar de forma fácil :) .